# Не работает CSS анимация в chrome

Tags: css, анимация

Не работает CSS анимация в chrome и opera, но работает в мозиле и даже интернет эксплорере, префиксы проставлены последней версией autoprefixer, версии браузеров последние... В чем загвоздка?

```css
body {
  /*ЛЕТНИЙ ФОН*/
  /*background:url(images/g12.jpg);}*/
  /*ЗИМНИЙ ФОН (ПАДАЮЩИЕ СНЕЖИНКИ)*/
  background: fixed, url(https://udsezon.ru/thumb/qyy419IWBadI3WCti5o-fw/90r90/913216/snezhinku.jpg);
  -webkit-animation: snegopad 30s linear infinite;
  animation: snegopad 30s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes snegopad {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0, 0% 563px;
  }
}

@keyframes snegopad {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0, 0% 563px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Много лишнего, у позиции 2 значения по `x` и по `y`, а не 4:

```css
body {
  background: url(https://udsezon.ru/thumb/qyy419IWBadI3WCti5o-fw/90r90/913216/snezhinku.jpg);
  animation: snegopad 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes snegopad {
  100% {
    background-position: 0 563px;
  }
}
```